# .NET 6 Integration tests in Visual Test give error - The specified version of Microsoft.NetCore.App or Microsoft.AspNetCore.App was not found

Tags: azure-devops, .net-6.0

I have migrated an integration test project from .Net Framework 4.8 to .NET6. The tests are running fine in local development machine. But when the same code is run using visual studio test task in Azure Devops release pipeline it is giving me the following error

> HTTP Error 500.31 - ANCM Failed to Find Native Dependencies.
>
> The specified version of Microsoft.NetCore.App or Microsoft.AspNetCore.App was not found.

Based on some of the suggestions for similar issue, I installed .Net 6 core runtime using use .net core task, and also gave console options as below to force the runtime version, but the error doesn't go away. The project is configured to run on Any CPU.

**console options:** `/Platform:x64 /Framework:.NetCoreApp,Version=v6.0 /logger:trx;LogFileName=netcore-results.trx`